# Appengine app is 404ing on /_ah/warmup out of nowhere; spinning up useless instances and causing a lot of cost

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I noticed that the App Engine mailing list suggested I direct my problems to Stack Overflow, so I am filing my bug report here.

Starting at 2013-06-25 23:05:40.756 US/Pacific  my app behavior significantly changed without any new deployments or other state modification.  A request from an iPhone client to `/` caused an `/_ah/warmup` request that `404`'d and began an unrelenting set of cascading failures which are still occurring when I enable the app.  Each new `404` is causing my app to spin up new instances which in turn `404` on `/_ah/warmup`, causing a cascade of unneeded instances **which have sucked up my entire daily budget and caused downtime on my site for over 16 hours!**

The application is currently disabled until I can resolve the issue, as it is just sucking up cost for no reason and spinning up dozens of unneeded instances in a matter of minutes.

In the last 24 hours I can see ~4 requests from non `/_ah/warmup/` endpoints, and **roughly 3k failing requests from `/_ah/warmup`!**

Again, to reiterate, my co-founder and I have made 0 code modifications to the site.  I don't even believe we've done any new datastore writes in the last 24 hours.  This sudden `/_ah/warmup` failure has come seemingly out of nowhere.

I did have `warmup` enabled by adding it to `inbound_services` in `app.yaml`.  I tried redeploying without any mention of `inbound_services` but that did not fix things.

I've also tried adding an `/_ah/warmup` handler directly into my main bottle app, but this did not get picked up it seems and the instances still failover.  This was true regardless of whether or not `inbound_services` was enabled with `warmup` in my `app.yaml`.

I cannot reproduce any of this locally and it has come seemingly out of nowhere.  It feels as though a recent appengine runtime update clobbered something I'm not aware of.  Any help would be much appreciated; this seems to be the only place I can file issues such as this for the entirety of the App Engine platform.

Comment: There were some anomalies yesterday.. the issue is still happening ? https://code.google.com/status/appengine

Comment: Yes I have disabled the app until I can stop the cascade of failing instances that are sucking up cost for no reason, and my site is currently down!

Comment: still happening ?   Have you tried killin the instances?

Comment: Still happening.  All instance are killed off every time I disable the application.  I just tried re-enabling and it immediately 404s and creates the cascading instance scaling issues I've reported.  **My site is still down and the application is still disabled in order to prevent my entire daily budget being sucked up by cascading instance failures**.  Would love help from someone on the Google App Engine team; I understand SO is the only place I can file these reports without paying them $150/month!!

Comment: What is the log message?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking me?  I'm not aware of any SO chat feature...  The log message is simply "This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application." It shows up with just info level logging; no errors even!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32485/discussion-between-mvanveen-and-nix)

Comment: Update: site is back up live after a redeploy on 06/28/13.  No code changes were made.

Comment: Sounds so familiar. Issues come our of nowhere and disappear suddenly, but only after you lose your sleep for couple of days trying to find the problem in your, in the place where it is not.